# Reset Service Fabric dev cluster using powershell

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is there a way to reset an existing dev cluster with powershell similar how the Service Fabric tray tool is doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There sure is (requires Admin privileges):

```
& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\DevClusterSetup.ps1" -PathToClusterDataRoot c:\SfDevCluster\data -PathToClusterLogRoot c:\SfDevCluster\log
```

You can change the path to \data and \log to where ever you want. Also, if you want the new 1-node dev cluster, add the -CreateOneNodeCluster option.

```
 & "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\DevClusterSetup.ps1" -PathToClusterDataRoot c:\SfDevCluster\data -PathToClusterLogRoot c:\SfDevCluster\log -CreateOneNodeCluster
```

Note that when you run this, any existing cluster will be removed and replaced.

Comment: Also requires -Auto to avoid typing confirmations.

Comment: Is there a way to stop and start existing dev cluster using powershell. It takes some time for the Service Fabric tray tool to pop up.

Comment: Pretty sure there's a way. The tray icon is just a decorator for powershell cmdlets.